xkcd 2957 - A Crossword Puzzle
The latest xkcd is a crossword puzzle. I thought it might be of interest to this community.

Solve it on Penpa+
Clues:
Across
1   Famous Pvt. Wilhelm quote (10)
11  IPv6 address record (4)
15  “CIPHERTEXT” decrypted with Vigenère key “CIPHERTEXT” (10)
16  8mm diameter battery (4)
17  “Warthog” attack aircraft (10)
18 Every third letter in the word for “inability to visualize” (4)
19  An acrostic hidden on the first page of the dictionary (15)
21  Default paper size in Europe (4)
22  First four unary strings (10)
23  Lysine codon (3)
24  40 CFR Part 63 subpart concerning asphalt pollution (7)
25  Top bond credit rating (3)
26  Audi coupe (5)
27  A pair of small remote batteries, when inserted (6)
29  Unofficial Howard Dean slogan (7)
32  A 4.0 report card (7)
33  The “Harlem Globetrotters of baseball” (vowels only) (6)
34  2018 Kiefer song (5)
35  Top Minor League tier (3)
36  Reply elicited by a dentist (7)
38  Anaa’s airport (3)
41  Macaulay Culkin’s review of aftershave (10)
43  Marketing agency trade grp. (4)
44  Soaring climax of Linda Eder’s Man of La Mancha (15)
46  Military flight community org. (4)
47  Iconic line from Tarzan(10)
48 Every other letter of Jimmy Wales’s birth state (4)
49  Warthog’s postscript after “They call me mister pig!” (10)
50  Message to Elsa in Frozen 2 (4)
51  Lola, when betting it all on Black 20 in Run Lola Run (10)
Down
1   Game featuring “a reckless disregard for gravity” (6)
2   1010101010101010101010102→16 (6)
3   Google phone released July ’22 (6)
4   It’s five times better than that other steak sauce (5)
5   ToHex(43690) (4)
6   Freddie Mercury lyric from Under Pressure (15)
7   Full-size Audi luxury sedan (8)
8   Fast path through a multiple choice marketing survey (7)
9   12356631 in base 26 (6)
10  Viral Jimmy Barnes chorus (15)
11  Ruby Rhod catchphrase (5)
12  badbeef + 9efcebbb (8)
13  In Wet Leg’s Ur Mum, what the singer has been practicing (8)
14  Refrain from Nora Reed bot (8)
20  Mario button presses to ascend Minas Tirith’s walls (7)
24  Vermont historic route north from Bennington (7)
26  High-budget video game (3)
28  Unorthodox Tic-Tac-Toe win (3)
29  String whose SHA-256 hash ends “…689510285e212385” (8)
30  Arnold’s remark to the Predator (8)
31  The vowels in the fire salamander’s binomial name (8)
32  Janet Leigh Psycho line (8)
34  Seven 440Hz pulses (7)
37  Audi luxury sports sedan (6)
38  A half-dozen eggs with reasonably firm yolks (6)
39  2-2-2-2-2-2 on a multitap phone keypad (6)
40  .- .- .- .- .- .- (6)
42  Rating for China’s best tourist attractions (5)
43  Standard drumstick size (5)
45  “The rain/in Spain/falls main-/ly on the plain” rhyme scheme (4)
The expected solution solves the grid and explains all clues.
Hint:

 In true xkcd fashion this puzzle is a bit of a joke. Be careful about how you enter answers containing numbers. Once you get the joke, solving gets a lot easier.


Down 29 would need a breakthrough in cryptography to solve! /j

My keybord hs one broken key. Sorry, I cn't solve your puzzle!

Spoiler: https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2957:_A_Crossword_Puzzle

@Jafe why did you add a bounty to this one hahaha :D

@BenjminWng No one solved it yet I guess ;) (dmn I relly should get tht keybord fixed)

Perhaps add the [tag:unsolved-mysteries] tag? This might take a while...

The link Florian F sent literally says that the grid is all the letter A with proof why is this bountied lol

I suspect Jafe has bountied this because he would like to see an answer which explains each clue. An answer was posted on this question that just filled the grid without helping the reader understand the meaning of these clues, many of which are very obscure. However, a useful answer - one worth the bounty - would help a reader to understand why and how this joke puzzle actually works! (And in a self-contained manner, not just via an external link...)

Okay, because I'm a fan of completeness (and I'm currently sick at home with Covid and time on my hands) here's a complete answer... The solution to this joke crossword is:

 
Image from @caPNCApn's deleted answer

And here are the clue explanations spelled out for all to see and understand in one place... (They are also available on this site but I have written my own...)
Across:

 1 Famous Pvt. Wilhelm quote (10) AAAAAAAAAA = The Wilhelm scream is a famous stock sound effect, used in many movies since the 1950's, named after Private Wilhelm, a character in The Charge at Feather River, a 1953 Western in which the character gets shot in the thigh with an arrow.
 11 IPv6 address record (4) AAAA = In the Domain Name System (DNS), hostnames are mapped to IPv6 addresses by AAAA ("quad-A") resource records.
 15 “CIPHERTEXT” decrypted with Vigenère key “CIPHERTEXT” (10) AAAAAAAAAA = Applying a Vigenère cipher using the same key and plaintext will simply make each letter in the string an 'A'.
 16 8mm diameter battery (4) AAAA = The quadruple-A battery size.
 17 “Warthog” attack aircraft (10) AAAAAAAAAA = The Fairchild Republic A-10 Thunderbolt II, also known as the 'Warthog'. 'A-10' gives us ten A's...
 18 Every third letter in the word for “inability to visualize” (4) AAAA = {A}PH{A}NT{A}SI{A}
 19 An acrostic hidden on the first page of the dictionary (15) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = This is just a joke, referring to the fact that the first letters of the words explained on the first page of the dictionary would all begin with 'A'.
 21 Default paper size in Europe (4) AAAA = A4 paper, thus four A's...
 22 First four unary strings (10) AAAAAAAAAA = A unary number system represents numbers using a single digit symbol, so you would have A, then AA, then AAA, then AAAA (if the chosen symbol was an 'A', of course).
 23 Lysine codon (3) AAA = The amino acid lysine is encoded by the codons AAA and AAG, but only one of these fits the theme of the puzzle!
 24 40 CFR Part 63 subpart concerning asphalt pollution (7) AAAAAAA = Look up this part of the Code of Federal Regulations in US law, and this is the title index number for this particular subpart.
 25 Top bond credit rating (7) AAA = The highest credit rating for bonds.
 26 Audi coupe (5) AAAAA = The Audi A5, giving us five A's...
 27 A pair of small remote batteries, when inserted (6) AAAAAA = Many remote controls take two AAA batteries, giving us six A's in total here...
 29 Unofficial Howard Dean slogan (7) AAAAAAA = A reference to a famous campaign-ending scream uttered by the Democrat hopeful, Howard Dean, during a rally (at about 0:35 in this video).
 32 A 4.0 report card (7) AAAAAAA = A 4.0 GPA in the US would be all A grades
 33 The “Harlem Globetrotters of baseball” (vowels only) (6) AAAAAA = The vowels from 'Savannah Bananas'
 34 2018 Kiefer song (5) AAAAA = Track on Kiefer's 2018 album, Happysad.
 35 Top Minor League tier (3) AAA = The name given to the top class in Minor League Baseball.
 36 Reply elicited by a dentist (7) AAAAAAA = The dentist asks you to say 'aaaaaaa!' in order to see clearly into your open mouth!
 38 Anaa’s airport (3) AAA = The IATA code for Anaa Airport
 41 Macaulay Culkin’s review of aftershave (10) AAAAAAAAAA = A movie scream, uttered by Macaulay Culkin's character, Kevin McCallister, in Home Alone (1990) (start at 0:55)
 43 Marketing agency trade grp. (4) AAAA = The American Association of Advertising Agencies, also known as the "4 A's"
 44 Soaring climax of Linda Eder’s Man of La Mancha (15) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = The long note held at the end of The Impossible Dream, the final song from the Broadway musical Man of La Mancha.
 46 Military flight community org. (4) AAAA = The Army Aviation Association of America, also known as 'quad-A' (four A's) after its initials...
 47 Iconic line from Tarzan (10) AAAAAAAAAA = What Tarzan commonly yells as he soars through the treetops on a vine...
 48 Every other letter of Jimmy Wales’s birth state (4) AAAA = Jimmy Wales is Alabama-born.
 49 Warthog’s postscript after “They call me mister pig!” (10) AAAAAAAAAA = Pumbaa's shout as he charges the hyenas to free Timon and Zazu from their grasp in the finale of The Lion King (1994)
 50 Message to Elsa in Frozen 2 (4) AAAA = In Frozen 2, Elsa repeatedly hears a four note message 'ah-ah ah-ah', notable at the beginning of the song, Into the Unknown.
 51 Lola, when betting it all on Black 20 in Run Lola Run (10) AAAAAAAAAA = Another movie scream, this time Lola in 1998's Run Lola Run.

Down:

 1 Game featuring “a reckless disregard for gravity” (6) AaAaAA!!! = The officially abbreviated title for the game AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA!!! — A Reckless Disregard for Gravity.
 2 1010101010101010101010102→16 (6) AAAAAA = What the number  101010101010101010101010 becomes when converted from binary to hexadecimal.
 3 Google phone released July ’22 (6) AAAAAA = The Pixel 6a, yielding six A's...
 4 It’s five times better than that other steak sauce (5) AAAAA = A tongue-in-cheek reference to A.1. Sauce, supposing that A.5. (or five A's) might be five times better than A.1.
 5 ToHex(43690) (4) AAAA = What the number 43690 becomes when converted from decimal to hexadecimal.
 6 Freddie Mercury lyric from Under Pressure (15) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = A very long 'aaahh' beginning at about 2:20 in this video.
 7 Full-size Audi luxury sedan (8) AAAAAAAA = The Audi A8, giving us eight A's...
 8 Fast path through a multiple choice marketing survey (7) AAAAAAA = What you would spell out if you repeatedly selected the first option in a 7-question multiple-choice survey with alphabetically-labelled options.
 9 12356631 in base 26 (6) AAAAAA = What the number  12356631 becomes when converted from decimal to base-26 letters (numerically, it would be 111111).
 10 Viral Jimmy Barnes chorus (15) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = A reference to the Kirin J Callinan song Big Enough - in the video Jimmy Barnes can be seen screaming this lyric during the chorus (see 2:22 in the video for an example).
 11 Ruby Rhod catchphrase (5) AAAAA = Another movie scream, this time Chris Tucker's character, Ruby Rhod, in The Fifth Element (1997).
 12 badbeef + 9efcebbb (8) AAAAAAAA = The sum in hexadecimal of badbeef and 9efcebbb.
 13 In Wet Leg’s Ur Mum, what the singer has been practicing (8) AAAAAAAA = The lyrics to Wet Leg's Ur Mum (NSFW) include the line "Okay, I've been practicing my longest and loudest scream... Okay, here we go... One, two, three, aaaaaaaa!"
 14 Refrain from Nora Reed bot (8) AAAAAAAA = A reference to the @infinite_scream Twitter bot, which used to regularly post content like this on its feed.
 20 Mario button presses to ascend Minas Tirith’s walls (7) AAAAAAA = Minas Tirith is a seven-walled city in the works of J.R.R. Tolkien. In the Mario computer games, the A-button was/is typically used to make him jump, so to jump the seven walls of Minas Tirith you would need to push seven A's...
 24 Vermont historic route north from Bennington (7) AAAAAAA = Vermont Route 7A, thus seven A's...
 26 High-budget video game (3) AAA = Triple-A games in the lingo.
 28 Unorthodox Tic-Tac-Toe win (3) AAA = Winning tic-tac-toe requires three X's or O's in a line; it would certainly be 'unorthodox' if using A's instead of one of these other letters!
 29 String whose SHA-256 hash ends “…689510285e212385” (8) AAAAAAAA = Try entering 'AAAAAAAA' into an online SHA-256 hash encoder - you'll get the output 'c34ab6abb7b2bb595bc25c3b388c872fd1d575819a8f55cc689510285e212385'...
 30 Arnold’s remark to the Predator (8) AAAAAAAA = A reference to Arnold Schwarzenegger's character's battle scream in Predator (1987)
 31 The vowels in the fire salamander’s binomial name (8) AAAAAAAA = The eight A's from Salamandra salamandra
 32 Janet Leigh Psycho line (8) AAAAAAAA = Another famous movie scream, this time from the shower scene in Psycho (1960)
 34 Seven 440Hz pulses (7) AAAAAAA = 440Hz is the frequency of the musical note A above middle C (also known as A4), the standard note used for tuning musical instruments in an orchestra. Seven of these, gives seven A's...
 37 Audi luxury sports sedan (6) AAAAAA = The Audi A6, giving us six A's...
 38 A half-dozen eggs with reasonably firm yolks (6) AAAAAA = In the US, eggs are given letter grades for quality. An egg with a reasonably firm yolk would be graded as 'A', thus half a dozen of these would be six A's...
 39 2-2-2-2-2-2 on a multitap phone keypad (6) AAAAAA = Pressing '2' on a multitap phone keypad produces the letter 'A'. Six times? Six A's...
 40 .- .- .- .- .- .- (6) AAAAAA = '.-' in Morse code stands for 'A'; this is repeated here 6 times...
 42 Rating for China’s best tourist attractions (5) AAAAA = The highest grade awarded by China's Ministry of Culture and Tourism.
 43 Standard drumstick size (5) AAAAA = A '5A' size drumstick is the industry standard.
 45 “The rain/in Spain/falls main-/ly on the plain” rhyme scheme (4) AAAA = the four lines end with the same rhyme; in standard notation this would be 'AAAA'.

Now to unwind in a relaxing bath - aaaaaaa!

Stiv,  I hope you start to feel better soon!

Ouch. I had "time on my hands" once, too. It was dreadful. ;) Get well soon.

rot13(V tenprshyyl nterr V nz qbvat guvf sbe gur obhagl!)
DOWN

(1) 


(2) changing to base 16 gives 'AAAAAA'


(3) 


I guess the 6a = AAAAAA counts


(4) best steak sauce is called A1 so five times better means A5


(5) 43690 in hexadecimal system is 'AAAA'


(6) In the song 'Under Pressure', Freddie Mercury was the musical attributor and he played the A5 note.


(7) Something about cars : "The 2023 $\underline{A8}$ is Audi's largest, most luxurious, most expensive sedan. Sitting above the mid-size A6, the A8 competes with the BMW 7 Series, Genesis G90 and Mercedes-Benz S-Class."


(8) Fastest path would be all choices A so 7 times A


(9) So there is this something called excel base 26, (where encryption is done as ; small examples ; a=1 b=2....26=z 27=aa 28=ab... so $26^5 + 26^4 + 26^3 + 26^2 + 26^1 + =AAAAA


(29) Use any online SHA-256 and hash 'AAAAAAAA' (letters guessed by common sense and length is given) and it gives : c34ab6abb7b2bb595bc25c3b388c872fd1d575819a8f55cc$\underline{689510285e212385}$


(40) Morse code for 'AAAAAA'


(45) If you know about rhyme schemes, then yes they all rhyme so its AAAAA

rot13(Thrff V'z n yvy' yngr gubhtu V fgnegrq lrfgreqnl, ohg V'ir tbg ybgf bs nffvtazragf gb qb fb lrnu...)

Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I'm afraid I don't see how this adds anything to the existing answer, which already explains all these clues. Please try and ensure you're not repeating answers that have already been given.

I'm afraid but I thought this a quizzing community so more than one people can answer the same question, though my answer to clues (DOWN 4), (DOWN 6) and (DOWN 9) vary from the existing answer

More than one person can answer the same question, but if there's already a full answer then a partial one probably isn't appropriate

My bad, should I delete my answer?

No its ok to keep it. You have represented it in a bit of different way.
